# group two columns and count in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple counts with dataframe
For example, if the df is as below:

```
> df
                             ID   lable     col1    col2 
                                                    
 1              Buckinghamshire       1        A       A      
 2 Cornwall and Isles of Scilly       2        B       B      
 3                        Devon       1        A       A      
 4                  Dunfermline       2        C       C      
 5                   Humberside       2        C       C      
 6                 Inner London       X        A       A      
 7                         Kent       X        A       A      
 8                    Kirkcaldy       1        C       C      
 9                   Lancashire       1        B       B      
10            Not known/missing       2        C       C
```

Desire output

```
> df2
     name    group        1        2      X
1    col1        A     4647     4858    108
1    col1        B   120456   146864   3502       
1    col1        C      258       53    111
2    col2        A    12247     1202     66
2    col2        B     4585      258      1
2    col2        C    32158    15426    477
```

How can I solve this so I can get desire output

Comment: Where do you get the values from? ie where did 4647 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear.

```
lines="
ID, label, col1, col2
              Buckinghamshire   ,    1    ,A,A      
 Cornwall and Isles of Scilly   ,    2    ,B,B      
                        Devon   ,    1    ,A,A      
                  Dunfermline   ,    2    ,C,C      
                   Humberside    ,   2    ,C,C"
con <- textConnection(lines)
data <- read.csv(con)
data$col2=trimws(data$col2)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
temp=gather(data, key="name", value="group",3:4)

temp2=temp[,c(2,3,4)] %>%
  group_by(name, group, label) %>%  summarise(count=n())

spread(temp2, key="label", value="count")
```

Result:

```
  name  group   `1`   `2`
  <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1 col1  A         2    NA
2 col1  B        NA     1
3 col1  C        NA     2
4 col2  A         2    NA
5 col2  B        NA     1
6 col2  C        NA     2
```